# QuickSort which correctly orders an array, but doesn't return it ordered

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I'm implementing Quick Sort in Python and I have little problem with it.
My function works perfectly recursively, but it doesn't return me the ordered array, and returns me just the original array.

In my code I have two versions of Quick Sort. `quickSort_2` works correctly and orders the list. Instead `quickSort_1` works exactly equal to `quicksort_1` , but gives me back the original array.

Any idea on why this is happening?

```
import random
import list

def partition(A,p):
    pivot=A[p]
    sup=0
    inf=len(A)-1
    while sup!=inf:
        while A[sup]<pivot:
            sup+=1
        while A[inf]>pivot:
            inf-=1
        list.swap(inf,sup,A) #swap
        print A
    return sup

def quickSort_1(A):
    if len(A)<=1:
        return A
    r=random.choice(range(0,len(A)-1))
    print A
    m=partition(A,r)
    return quickSort_1(A[:m+1])+quickSort_2(A[m+1:])

def quickSort_2(A):
    if len(A)<=1:
        return A
    r=random.choice(range(0,len(A)-1))
    print A
    m=partition(A,r)
    quickSort_1(A[:m+1])
    quickSort_2(A[m+1:])
    return A
```

Comment: Please could you check the last paragraph? I think you put some methods in the wrong way :P. Which one is running good and which is returning in bad state?
Anyway I think is the second version the one with problems. The reason is you're computing quickSort for each part of the array but returning the original one, A.Try to append the result of both invocations and return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the original array `A` in your second function.

What you should do is save the sorted array as your original array and `return` this value. Something like this:

```
A_new = quickSort_1(A[:m+1])+quickSort_2(A[m+1:])
return A_new
```

Since you are altering the array A in the scope of the function `quickSort_1` or `quickSort_2`, there is no alteration of the original array `A`.

Comment: Thanks, i was confused with another version of quicksort created by my friend based on the approach of quicksort_2. The difference was that he used an if conditon on index, after he call quicksort on two sublistes, and just in the end (when quicksort order the entire list)  he uses return on A.

Comment: No problem. If it solved your problem, consider marking the answer as accepted to close the question. Thanks :)